# Rails 3 - "undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass" in many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having an issue with a many to many relationship in Rails 3. The 3 models involved here are:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :protocol, :address, :status, :room_id

  belongs_to :room

  has_many :device_abilities
  has_many :abilities, :through => :device_abilities
end

class Ability < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :device_abilities
  has_many :devices, :through => :device_abilities
end

class DeviceAbility < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :ability
end
```

and I have the following in my seed file for testing:

```
device_abilities = DeviceAbility.create([
  { device_id: '1', ability_id: '1'},
  { device_id: '1', ability_id: '2'},
  { device_id: '1', ability_id: '3'},
  { device_id: '1', ability_id: '4'},
  { device_id: '1', ability_id: '5'},
  { device_id: '2', ability_id: '1'},
  { device_id: '2', ability_id: '2'},
  { device_id: '2', ability_id: '3'},
  { device_id: '2', ability_id: '4'},
  { device_id: '2', ability_id: '5'}
  ])
```

(the actual devices and abilities are also defined, and I can interact with them normally).

I am getting the unusual error when I attempt to do

```
def show
  @device = Device.find(params[:id])
  puts @device.abilities
end
```

(the puts is for debugging; I can also not use this if i put it into a variable). The error is:

```
undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

update:

as requested, the error trace:

```
app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:13:in `puts'
app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:13:in `puts'
app/controllers/devices_controller.rb:13:in `show'
```

and the schema is:

```
create_table "abilities", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "devices", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "protocol"
    t.string   "address"
    t.boolean  "status"
    t.integer  "room_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "device_abilities", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "device_id"
    t.integer  "ability_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comment: Can you post schema.rb for those models?

Comment: I am confident there is something going wrong when assigning the abilities to the devices; it seems like `@device.abilities` is always nil, when it should contain something - could this be because I am creating it with a seed file (or the way I am seeding it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I *finally* managed to narrow this down to a section of code that I put in my environment.rb file:

```
class Array
  def sum
      self.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
  end
end
```

This is designed to allow me to do `array.sum` and get an answer, which has been working well up to now. I would very much appreciate any comments as to why this is causing such a problem here, and whether there is a way I can work around this, since other sections of my code rely on this method.

Thanks!

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer... For any that use this... note that this can be shortened using reduce with "self.reduce(:+)"

Comment: I had `def sum; inject(:+); end`. I fixed it with `def sum; super || inject(:+); end`. (YMMV.)

Answer (score 3):

Answered here: [Rails 3.2 Uniqueness validation raises undefined method 'zero?' for nil:Nilclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289535/rails-3-2-uniqueness-validation-raises-undefined-method-zero-for-nilnilclass)

Your `sum` method is being added to `Array` and overriding Rails' own `Enumerable#sum`.

> How to fix it?
>
> Have you written a method named sum, perhaps within a module named
>   Enumerable or Array? If so, that's a good place to start. You could
>   rename your method, or you could try changing your method to match the
>   Rails method by replacing your #sum code with this code:
>
> module Enumerable   def sum(identity = 0, &block)
>       if block_given?
>         map(&block).sum(identity)
>       else
>         inject(:+) || identity
>       end   end end
>   (again: take from [Rails 3.2 Uniqueness validation raises undefined method 'zero?' for nil:Nilclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289535/rails-3-2-uniqueness-validation-raises-undefined-method-zero-for-nilnilclass))

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you dont use `:dependent => :destroy`The default behavior is to set the `foreign_key` to `nil`. So if you have a object of `DeviceAbility` and associate a `Device`object and a `Ability` object thats okay but when you delete one of them you cant work with it anymore because the deleted one is `nil` then. And `nil` doesnt have method called `zero?`. You could demiter that useing this query:

```
DeviceAbility.where("device_id IS NULL OR ability_id IS NULL")
```

If that returns any results then you know whats the reason for the trouble!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work - i tried adding `:dependent => :destroy` to both the device and ability models, but to no avail.

Comment: This doenst work if there is already a failure! It just prevents future fails! Does `DeviceAbility.where("device_id IS NULL OR ability_id IS NULL")` return anything?

Comment: `DeviceAbility.where("device_id IS NULL OR ability_id IS NULL").to_s` returns `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc7a1955928>` - I should point out that each time I have been making changes, I am going back and doing `rake db:migrate:reset` and `rake db:seed` to avoid errors.

Comment: why the hell are you adding `to_s`? Leave that away and tell my if that returns any objects!

Comment: Apologies, it returned a "can not convert to string" error originally because I tried to append it to a string for easy reading in the console. I have removed the to_s, and it is returning blank (nothing is printed in the console).

Comment: Okay then plase post the code of the `devices_controller` and the view