# undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass on Devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm installing Devise and I'm getting a undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass when trying to register a new user. Routing seams ok, as other pages such as sign in, sign up, lost password is showing up.

The error message:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass
```

My Class User is as follows:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable #, :encryptable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :password_salt
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

end
```

The migration is running OK as:

```
    class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      t.string :authentication_token

      t.string :password_salt

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"MNwIeldQzcBbakbcLkbcIlNYiKQ72F3nJyqHOsDdRoM=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"email@example.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up",
 "locale"=>"en"}
```

Devise Version:
2.1.2

Ruby version:

```
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

Rails version:

```
Rails 3.2.13
```

Comment: My problem is on **Descriptive_statistics** gem and the solution is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289535/rails-3-2-uniqueness-validation-raises-undefined-method-zero-for-nilnilclass)